# Every CUDA block has the same blockIdx.z

Tags: cuda

Outside kernel:

```
dim3 block(32, 32, 1);
printf("rows = %u\n", rows);
dim3 grid(8, 8, rows);
forward_step1<<<block, grid>>>(weight_D, a_D, res1_D, columns);
```

Inside kernel:

```
unsigned int tid = blockDim.x*threadIdx.y + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.z;
unsigned int j = (gridDim.x*blockIdx.y+blockIdx.x)*blockDim.x*blockDim.y + tid;
if (j==0) printf("%u\n", i);
```

And the result:

> rows = 3
>   0
>   0
>   0

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the kernel invocation is:

```
kernel<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(arguments)
```

You seem to have swapped the `grid_size` and `block_size` arguments. Your grid size is `(32, 32, 1)` and block size `(8, 8, rows)`.